# RecyclerView with images scroll unsmooth (lags)

Tags: java, android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have a common problem - recyclerView lags and scroll unsmooth. I've read many tutorials and implemented their methods, but no success. I have imageView and textView in each raw of recycleView. I tried to use image loaders like Glide or Picasso, but there are some delay when load images. What is the reason of bad performance? Here is row layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:text="@string/textview"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text2" />
```

and list layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
```

>

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:animationCache="false"
    />
```

CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Image> DrinkArrayList;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Image> DrinkArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.DrinkArrayList = DrinkArrayList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.my_image_list, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Image image = DrinkArrayList.get(position);
    holder.name1.setText(image.getName());
    holder.iv1.setImageResource(image.getImageResourceId());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.DrinkArrayList.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
   private TextView name1;
   private ImageView iv1;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.name1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        this.iv1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    }
}
```

}

related methods in activity:

```
RecyclerView listDrinks2 = findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    listDrinks2.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, DrinkArrayList));
    listDrinks2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Comment: cant see anything wrong (performace related). are images too big?

Comment: I think you should use glide or picasso for image loading.

Comment: @Alberto Cappellina, not that big

Comment: if you remove the holder.iv1.setImageResource(image.getImageResourceId()); line, things get better ?

Comment: each image us about 130Kb, its about 300 images is recyclerview

Comment: use an image loading and caching library like Glide, Fresco or Picasso

Comment: @Alberto Cappellina, if I remove holder.iv1.setImageResource(image.getImageResourceId()); how can I load Image to recyclerview?

Comment: it's a step to understand if are the images the problem here. you'll put them back later

Comment: I removed this line and images disappear

Comment: 130kb is actually quite big. How many images do you want to display at the same time?

Comment: @Eselfar, I have 2-3 images at the screen, as they have different height

Comment: You should probably resize them and provide a version for each screen density (hdpi, mdpi,...). And use Glide or Picasso, first time you'll have a little delay before the image is displayed (but not that much, especially if your images are sized correctly) but the UI will not be laggy